# What does it mean to die like mere men as stated in Psalm 82:7

Tags: psalms

Please I want clarification on ye shall die like mere men, after God creating as in His own image.

Comment: You’re assuming these in v7 are men? Adam was made in the image of God, or put differently, Adam was God’s imager/representative on earth. There is nothing in the text that a) says they are humans v7 indicates they are immortal b) they are made in God’s image.

Comment: Man's mortality is contrasted with God's immortality. The former is due to sin (the previous four verses), as with Adam and Eve in paradise. Both (Israel, by obeying the Mosaic Law, and the first men, by hearkening to God's advice) had the chance to become immortal, rather than die like (the rest of) men.

Comment: @ERNESTK Hi Ernest, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being created in God's image does not mean being created in the physical sense. Rather, it means that humans have intelligence, can reason, make choices, rational and have a moral consciousness or a knowledge or right and wrong, of good and evil.

The context of Psalm 82 is that God stands in His own congregation and judges in the midst of the rulers/judges. Psalm 82:1-2. In other words, God is outlining the fact that these "elohiym" "judge," who act on behalf of God are corrupt in their judgment.

At verse 6 God says, Sure, I said "You are gods, And all of you are sons of the Most High, verse 7, Nevertheless or However and by contrast, they will die like the men they are despite their power and authority.

It should be noted that these judges are "NOT" actual ontological deities claimed by some organizations and others who believe men can become gods, or even are gods.

Comment: It does not say “*like the men **they are**”*. Nor is it a punishment to tell a mortal you will die. Your whole explanation circles around the idea that these elohim are men yet they are present in the divine council v1 and this same divine council in psalm 89:5-7 is held in the SKY. I was unaware that men during OT times had meeting in the sky. Also holy ones is a term given to the heavenly beings or the elohim or the gods.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Who have you been reading, Michael Heiser? I'm well acquainted with his work from a few years back on Psalm 82:6. He talks about it here: https://faithlife.com/posts/776815 Your welcome to your opinion just as I am and I disagree with his take even though a few of my Trinitarian friends agree with him. Btw, I addressed the posters specific question and did not bring up why Jesus quoted Psalm 82:6. I do have a Biblical answer just like Mr. Heiser has his take.

Comment: I beg to differ that you have provided a biblical answer much less a satisfactory one at that. You’re explanation is that the elohim are judges, you infer/assume but don’t explicitly state these are human, nor explain why they are human. When confronted with v7 the punishment of death, which makes no sense given according to you they are human and are mortal already, so why is that a punishment, seeing its future tense?

Comment: @NihilSineDeo These are men/human beings that are appointed to judge issues. Vs2, "How long will you judge unjustly, And show partiality to the wicked?" Vs3, "Do justice to the afflicted and destitute. Vs4, Rescue the weak and needy. Who specifically makes up this so-called council? Do you mean they are actual gods? Are they addressed as "gods" metaphorically? Who are they? Also, according to Genesis 9:6 it was God who gave man a judiciary system. "Whoever sheds man's blood, BY MAN his blood shall be shed." Isaiah 3:17, Learn to do good, seek justice, defend the orphan, plead for the widow."

Comment: “When the Most High gave to the nations their inheritance, when he divided mankind, he fixed the borders of the peoples according to the number of the **sons of God**.”
‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭32:8‬ ‭the divine council was made up of **Benei ha’Elohim**. This council does not consist of humans.

Answer (score 0):

> “I said, “You are gods, sons of the Most High, all of you; nevertheless, like men you shall die, and fall like any prince.””
> ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭82:6-7‬ ‭

#### Elohim qualifier

While there are those who will claim that humans were also referred to as elohim, the Bible never calls any human an elohim. Moses was said to be **like** an elohim to pharoah Exodus 4:16. The passages with the elohim, which in **translation**, speaks of judges puts the emphasis on the men being the judges but the Hebrew, especially in other similar passages puts the emphasis on God being the judge Exodus 21:6, 22:8-9. The spirit that the woman with familiar spirits called from the dead was referred to as an elohim 1 Samuel 28:13 but while it’s debatable it was Samuel, it certainly wasn’t a human.

#### New Testament

Jesus was accused of claiming to be god though he was clearly a human. That adds to the argument that no one believed, nor claimed humans were an elohim

> “The Jews answered him, “It is not for a good work that we are going to stone you but for blasphemy, **because you, being a man, make yourself God**.” Jesus answered them, “Is it not written in your Law, ‘I said, you are gods’? If he called them gods to whom the word of God came—and Scripture cannot be broken—”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭10:33-35‬ ‭

The word of God came to those whom God was addressing in Psalm 82. They were called elohim. They were placed over the nations to judge the nations as described in Deuteronomy 32:8 DSS,LXX which is described in Psalm 82:2-5 as being their duty.

The leaders in Jesus’ time did not see it possible for men to be elohim. They also didn’t want to acknowledge any other gods either. Jesus was making the point that there are many elohim, not just one. And that God has many He calls sons. Jesus went forward not just claiming to be one of the elohim (benei ha’Elohim) but God incarnate.

> “but if I do them, even though you do not believe me, believe the works, that you may know and understand that the **Father is in me and I am in the Father**.””
> ‭‭John‬ ‭10:38‬ ‭

#### Verse 7 OP’s dilemma.

If these were men, there would be no punishment telling them they will die like men, for men already die. If instead they were heavenly beings as all the OT passages depicts every elohim, then telling them they will die like men was indeed a punishment especially seeing they were immortal.

Comment: To say the Bible never calls any human 'elohim' and then quote Exodus 21:6, 22:8-9, really astounding.

Comment: @user21676 it does, only in translation which is an interpretation, only there does it say that these were humans. The Hebrew and other corroborating passages makes it clear they are to come to God and not to judges or to men.

Comment: @user21676 You need to consider those Exodus verses with a Hebraic lens. It clearly in **both** cases refers to doing something in the presence of your forefathers (ancestors, = ‘door, doorpost, symbolic of!) . Therefore the translation of Elohim to ‘judges’ is clearly a westernised interpretation, as the ‘Elohim’ clearly refers to ‘dead’ forefathers, i.e. spiritual entities!

Comment: What about Exodus 22:28, and its correlation with both Exodus 18:21-22 and Deut. 1:12-16? How could anybody really think in that verse, given the correlation, that 'elohim' in no way referenced the people(rulers) of Israel? I mean how could anyone really read the first part of that verse as referring only to God, and then read the second part as referring to people(Heb. 'ruler' - collective noun[cmp. Num 1:44,4:46,7:2]), without making the connection between the two, besides the other two references[Exd 21:6,22:8-9]?

Comment: @user21676 the key word here is elohim, not rulers, leaders. They were never called elohim. Moses was likened to elohim. Moses was not an elohim. The rulers were rulers. Those that were brought before elohim were brought before elohim not before rulers. They were brought before God. I understand you like the translated version but it doesn’t corroborate I’ll find you examples why this is so. I believe I have an answer here on this stack if I can find it on this very subject.

Comment: Maybe I can you save you the time of telling me there is only one God and they aren't God, so therefore I'm wrong, and so forth. This reply was only about whether the absolute statement ' the Bible never calls any human an elohim', that is in any way, form, or concept(e.g. name), was accurate.

Comment: I’m not sure I understood your comment @user21676 and I assume more highly of you, not lesser. My intention is not to prove your right or wrong but to get to the truth through dialogue. No human has been called an elohim outright. None. Interpretation of the Hebrew in translation claims that elohim refers to human judges originating from oral tradition but not based on Scriptural backing, nor on grammar. Sure the contextual grammar is ambiguous as to whether this elohim is singular or plural but that’s not a case for claiming judges. Especially since it’s inconclusive grammatically speaking.

Comment: Nihil, you are simply incorrect.  @user21676 has a very valid point.  Hebrew uses "Elohim" to reference _any_ supernatural being, and it also uses the term to reference rulers, judges, and those who are able to discern between good and evil.  God Himself calls people "Elohim."  Ps. 82:6: "I have said, Ye are gods ["אֱלֹהִ֣ים" - Elohim]; and all of you are children of the most High." Jesus confirms this.  John 10:34:35: "Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, Ye are gods? If he called them gods, unto whom the word of God came, and the scripture cannot be broken; . . ."

Comment: @polyhat that is not how Hebrews understood Elohim. That is how modern theologians interpret elohim to include judges but it was not this was from the beginning. Those children of God that Jesus is quoting are heavenly beings not humans.Refer to Cyrus Gordon addressed this issue in JBL (54.3 [1935]: 139-44), and that pretty much settled the issue for academia, save a short note on Psalm 82 by one Roger O’Callaghan in CBQ (15 [1953]: 311-14) that was never considered very convincing. אלהים does not equal judges or humans